# SQlite returns 0

Tags: android, sqlite

Let me start of by explaining how I insert and return data from SQLite.

First I create the table like this:

```
private static final String CREATE_TABLE_STUDENT_LESSON = " create table STUDENTSPECIFICLESSON ( _id TEXT , _viewID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT , _LESSON_TITLE TEXT , _LESSON_DATE TEXT , _LESSON_PROBLEM TEXT );";

public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_STUDENT_LESSON);
}
```

Then I insert into the table like this in SQLite:

```
public void insertLesson(String _id, String lessonTitle, String lessonDate, String lessonProblem) {
    ContentValues contentValue = new ContentValues();
    contentValue.put(SQLiteHelper._ID, _id);
    contentValue.put(SQLiteHelper.LESSON_TITLE, lessonTitle);
    contentValue.put(SQLiteHelper.LESSON_DATE, lessonDate);
    contentValue.put(SQLiteHelper.LESSON_PROBLEM, lessonProblem);
    this.getWritableDatabase().insert(SQLiteHelper.TABLE_NAME_STUDENTSPECIFICLESSON, null, contentValue);
}
```

And I insert it from the Activity like this:

```
sqLiteHelper.insertLesson(id,etLessonTitle.getText().toString(),currentDateandTime,etLessonProbStu.getText().toString());
```

You will notice that I have created `_viewID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT` I'm using this to get the specific ViewHolder in my Adapter.

I get this `_viewID` by doing this:

```
public String getLessonViewHolderID(String _path){
    String id = null;

    Cursor cursor = getReadableDatabase().rawQuery("Select "+SQLiteHelper._viewID+" from "+SQLiteHelper.TABLE_NAME_STUDENTSPECIFICLESSON+" Where "
            +SQLiteHelper.LESSON_TITLE +"='"+_path+"'",null);

    if (cursor != null) {
        cursor.moveToFirst();
    }
    if (cursor == null) {
    } else if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            id = String.valueOf(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(SQLiteHelper._viewID)));

        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        cursor.close();
    } else {

    }
    return id;
}
```

This works perfectly and returns the `_viewId` correctly as expected.

---

I then try to get `_LESSON_PROBLEM` from SQLite by doing this:

```
public String getLessonProblem(String _id){


    String id = null;

    Cursor cursor = getReadableDatabase().rawQuery("Select _LESSON_PROBLEM from "+SQLiteHelper.TABLE_NAME_STUDENTSPECIFICLESSON+" Where "
            +SQLiteHelper._viewID +"='"+_id+"'",null);


    if (cursor != null) {
        cursor.moveToFirst();
    }
    if (cursor == null) {
    } else if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            id = String.valueOf(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("_LESSON_PROBLEM")));

        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        cursor.close();
    } else {

    }
    return id;

}
```

and from my `Adapter` I call:

```
String lessonProblem = helper.getLessonProblem(viewId);
```

The above `String lessonProblem` will then return `0`.

I have checked my database and all the data is inserted correctly, here is a image of my database:

[image: myDatabase]

I can't understand why it is returning 0 when clearly it is not, can someone please help me point out what the issue may be?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> ```
> id = String.valueOf(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("_LESSON_PROBLEM")));
> ```

You're getting a string value as an int and then converting that to a string. Change that to something like

```
id = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("_LESSON_PROBLEM"));
```

Answer (score 7):

Sloppy mistake. You should use [**`getString()`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#getString(int)) instead of [**`getInt()`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#getInt(int)).

> Returns the value of the requested column as a String. The result and
>   whether this method throws an exception when the column value is null
>   or the column type is not a string type is implementation-defined.

**Finally**

```
cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("_LESSON_PROBLEM"));
```

Comment: Thank you very much for answering, I will be accepting @laalto answer, just because he answered first. Thank you once again.

Comment: For what it's worth, you linked to the wrong getString(), and there's an extra `)` close paren too.

Comment: Thank you both for answering.